How to Apply Blur and Noise to imported Images Using TikZ?
I'm trying to create the figure below using TikZ. That figure consists of a 2x3 grid collage with the following sub-images:

Target - the original image.
Denoising - the image with added noise.
Deblurring - a blurred version of the image.
Superresolution - a lower-resolution version of the image.
Interpolation - an image with black point or squares.
Inpainting - the image with a black square masking part of it.


I am using the same image file for all sub-images and applying different effects. Here is the image file I used.
I have encountered some difficulties with the following:

Applying Gaussian Blur to Included Image Files: I am unsure how to correctly implement Gaussian blur (or any blur) directly to the included images.
Adding Noise to Included Image Files: I need a method to add noise to the images.
Aligning Labels: Ensuring that the labels are correctly aligned as shown in the example.
Long Compilation Time: I have noticed that my code takes a long time to compile and I don't know why.

Here is the code I have so far:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    img/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0},
    label/.style={font=\footnotesize,below}
]

% Original image
\node[img] (a) at (0,4) {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{parrot}};
\node[label] at (a.south) {(a) Target $\mathbf{x}^\ast$};

% Noisy image
\begin{scope}
    \clip (2.6,3.1) rectangle (5.1,5.6);
    \node[img] at (3.85,4.35) {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{parrot}};
    \foreach \x in {0,0.02,...,2.5} {
        \foreach \y in {0,0.02,...,2.5} {
            \pgfmathrandomitem{\noise}{noise}
            \fill[white,opacity=\noise] (2.6+\x,3.1+\y) rectangle ++(0.02,0.02);
        }
    }
\end{scope}
\node[label] at (3.85,3.1) {(b) Denoising $y$};

% Blurred image
\node[img] (c) at (7.7,4.35) {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{parrot}};
\begin{scope}
    \clip (6.45,3.1) rectangle (8.95,5.6);
    \foreach \i in {1,...,15} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\op}{0.07/\i}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\shift}{0.03*\i}
        \node[img,opacity=\op] at (7.7+\shift,4.35+\shift) {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{parrot}};
        \node[img,opacity=\op] at (7.7-\shift,4.35-\shift) {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{parrot}};
    }
\end{scope}
\node[label] at (c.south) {(c) Deblurring $y$};

% Low resolution image
\node[img] (d) at (0,1) {\includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{parrot}};
\node[label] at (d.south) {(d) Superresolution $y$};

% Degraded image
\begin{scope}
    \clip (2.6,0.1) rectangle (5.1,2.6);
    \node[img] at (3.85,1.35) {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{parrot}};
    \foreach \x in {0,0.05,...,2.5} {
        \foreach \y in {0,0.05,...,2.5} {
            \pgfmathrandomitem{\noise}{noise}
            \fill[black,opacity=\noise] (2.6+\x,0.1+\y) rectangle ++(0.05,0.05);
        }
    }
\end{scope}
\node[label] at (3.85,0.1) {(e) Interpolation $y$};

% Inpainting image
\node[img] (f) at (7.7,1.35) {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{parrot}};
\fill[black] (7.2,1.6) rectangle (8.2,2.1);
\node[label] at (f.south) {(f) Inpainting $y$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

and this is how it looks

Thank you!

Consider an image manipulation tool like gimp or ImageMagick to generate images with the properies you need.

Thank you for your reply. You're right; However, I thought it would be better to handle some of these manipulations with a single image directly in LaTeX. I understand that LaTeX isn't typically used for this kind of image processing, but if TikZ could provide some simple implementations, it would be great. Otherwise, I'll use image editing software as you suggested. @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
